# How can I test secure pages on Zend Developer Cloud (phpcloud.com)

Tags: zend-framework, ssl, ssl-certificate

I found the following link that mentions the existence of a shared ssl support to be used on phpcloud.com to test secure pages, but that is it!

https://getsatisfaction.com/zend_technologies/topics/add_own_ssl_certs_support

Here's an extract:

"We don't have a plan to support external SSL certificated.

my.phpcloud.com is a development environment not production and as such, we provide a shared SSL support for all users running in this system. You are more than welcome to develop and test your secure pages but using our certificate. "

So how do I go about testing my secure pages on phpcloud.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] to detect secure pages after the load balancer.